# Is there a way i can get the data from the native checkout form in Shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, shopify-template, liquid-layout

I am tasked with adding address validation into the checkout, therefore I am wondering if there is a way to get the user input from this native checkout form using LIQUID preferably or any other method possible. I have seen apps that do this, therefore I am assuming its possible at some level although Shopify doesn't grant open access to this part of their system, it's just rendered in from what I have seen. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is your store Plus, only plus stores can have access to the checkout file. In addition liquid is a back-end language, so you can communicate with a front-end form using liquid, the only way to "validate" the address is to use Javascript and for that (or any other tweak) you need your store to be on the Plus plan.

Comment: Yes it is plus, I understand I will seek a JS solution.